# Determine if possible to reach y from x in a certain number of steps in Java

Tags: java

I'm not far off from a beginner at Java and this community, so hello! I can't seem to find a question similar to mine, but I am currently working on a problem as follows:

> The goal is to start with a certain integer *x*, a maximum amount of steps integer *i*, and a target integer *y* to determine if *x* can reach *y* within *i* steps.
>
> Each step gives you two options:
>
> - If the integer is even, you can remove half of the integer and
>   continue to the next step.
> - Or, you can add an additional amount to the integer that the user would specify.
>
> The user would input a starting value, a target value, a value for the maximum number of steps, and a value for if you want to add to your value each step.

My goal with this program is to determine if it is possible to win or not based on what values are given. I know that I am supposed to use a boolean method with these 4 values inputted from the user and return if it is or isn't possible to win, but I am kind of lost on how to go about checking to see.

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Just try implementing what was described above. If you perform `i` steps and still have not reached your goal you know that you can't reach it in `i` steps

Comment: Please read this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @larsgrefer, I never asked for you to give me the answer. I was asking for a push in the right direction. I know this website isn't for for that, but I'm really trying to learn. I'll know not to post things on here now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just simulate the whole process. This is necessary as the user is allowed to make arbitrary inputs, so you won't find any *direct solution*.

For the decisions let's assume we get an `ArrayList` containing positive `Integer`s to add or something negative like `-1` if the user wants to halve the value. Let's further assume that the inputs of the user are correct, i.e. `-1` only occurs in the list if the current value is even and not odd.

Here is the method solving the problem by simulation:

```
public boolean isReachable(int start, int target, int maxSteps,
        ArrayList<Integer> decisions) {
    // Problem is trivial
    if (start == target) {
        return true;
    }

    // Start the simulation
    int value = start;
    for (int step = 0; step < maxSteps; step++) {
        int decision = decisions.get(step);

        if (decision < 0) {
            if (value % 2 != 0) {
                // Is not even but assumed to be
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            value = value / 2;
        } else {
            value += decision;
        }

        // Check the value at the end of the step
        if (value == target) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Not reachable if still not finished
    return false;
}
```

---

Note that in general, if you are allowed to construct the user decisions, the problem is always solvable, for every start and target.

Therefore, if `start` is **smaller** than `target`, add `target - start` in the first step. You then receive `start + (target - start) = target`.

If `start` is **greater** than `target`, make sure it is **even** (if not, just add `1`). Then you are allowed to halve the value. Repeat if still greater. Once the value is smaller than `target` just add the difference like in the first case.

The only unsolvable case would be if `target` is allowed to be negative while not allowed to *add* negative values. If `start` then is greater than `target` you have no chance to decrease it beyond `1`.

Comment: I really thank you for taking the time to explain this. I didn't mean to come off as asking for someone to do it for me, I was just wanting to know ways in which I could attack this problem. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry that I've taken the opportunity to create this on your own away from you.